# Loops in Javascript starting at wrong index in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

I have a form that is filled with students names line four, and depending on how many students there are in the class, I need varying numbers of pages.  Depending on the type of sheet, each sheet would hold either 8 or 9 students.

I have an outer loop to deal with each sheet, and an inner loop to deal with each name on that row.  Whenever the number of students was a multiple of 8 or 9 (depending on the sheet), the last name would be skipped.  When I started looking into the problem and checking the values of my counters, I noticed that

1. the first thing printed in the logger output is the line "i value: " and its value, 1
2. the index i starts at 1, and h starts at 7, despite being initialized at 0

This  is extremely perplexing (not to mention frustrating).

Here is the code:

```
function insertNames(mealcountDoc, className, namesInTheClass, constructionDetails){
Logger.log("\nEntered 'insertNames' function\n");
  namesInTheClass = namesInTheClass.sort();
  var newlyCreatedSheet = mealcountDoc.getSheetByName(className);

// loop for each row in the tab
  var numOfRowsOfMealcounts = Math.ceil(namesInTheClass.length/constructionDetails.namesPerRow);
  for(var i = 0; i < numOfRowsOfMealcounts; i++){
  Logger.log("i value just after entering outer loop: " + i);
//  Logger.log("h value just after entering outer loop: " + h);
    //    var countOfStudentsEntered = 0;
    var classDetailsInfoRow = (i * 41 + 3);
    var footerRow = (i * 41 + 41);
    newlyCreatedSheet.getRange(classDetailsInfoRow - 2, mealcountDataPlacement.className).setValue(className).setHorizontalAlignment('Left');
    newlyCreatedSheet.getRange(classDetailsInfoRow, mealcountDataPlacement.nameOfInstitution).setValue(mealcountDoc.getName().slice(0, mealcountDoc.getName().indexOf("-")-1)).setHorizontalAlignment('Left');
    newlyCreatedSheet.getRange(classDetailsInfoRow, mealcountDataPlacement.agreementNum).setValue(constructionDetails.agreementNumber).setHorizontalAlignment('Left');
    newlyCreatedSheet.getRange(classDetailsInfoRow, mealcountDataPlacement.facilityNameAndNum).setValue(mealcountDoc.getName().slice(0, mealcountDoc.getName().indexOf("-")-1)).setHorizontalAlignment('Left');
    newlyCreatedSheet.getRange(classDetailsInfoRow, mealcountDataPlacement.monthYear).setValue(constructionDetails.monthAsAWord + " " + constructionDetails.currentYear).setHorizontalAlignment('Left');
    newlyCreatedSheet.getRange(classDetailsInfoRow, mealcountDataPlacement.serviceDays).setValue(constructionDetails.numOfServiceDays).setHorizontalAlignment('Left');
    newlyCreatedSheet.getRange(footerRow, mealcountDataPlacement.pageNumber).setValue("Page " + (i + 1) + " of " + numOfRowsOfMealcounts).setHorizontalAlignment('Left');
    
    var startingRow = (i * 41 + 4);
    var loopLimit = constructionDetails.namesPerRow
    
    // loop for each name
    // if-else statement deals with the final row containing less than a full row of names (8 or 9, dep on type of sheet)
    if(numOfRowsOfMealcounts - i <= 1 && namesInTheClass.length % constructionDetails.namesPerRow != 0){
      loopLimit = namesInTheClass.length % constructionDetails.namesPerRow;
    }
    for(var h = 0; h < loopLimit; h++){
      Logger.log("\n");
      Logger.log(constructionDetails);
      Logger.log(namesInTheClass);
      Logger.log("i value: " + i );
      Logger.log("h value: " + h );
      Logger.log(namesInTheClass[i * constructionDetails.namesPerRow + h][1]+ "\n" + namesInTheClass[i * constructionDetails.namesPerRow + h][0]);
      newlyCreatedSheet.getRange(startingRow,h * constructionDetails.numOfColsPerEntry + 2,1,1).setValue(namesInTheClass[i * constructionDetails.namesPerRow + h][1]+ "\n" + namesInTheClass[i * constructionDetails.namesPerRow + h][0]);
    }    
  }
```

Logs:

```
Stackdriver logs
Aug 19, 2020, 4:12:44 PM
Info
i value here: 1
Aug 19, 2020, 4:12:44 PM
Info
h value here: 7
Aug 19, 2020, 4:12:44 PM
Info
Cayden
Jimenez
Aug 19, 2020, 4:12:44 PM
Info
i value just after entering outer loop: 2
Aug 19, 2020, 4:12:44 PM
Info

Aug 19, 2020, 4:12:44 PM
Info
{currentYear=2020, initNumberOfCols=5.0, agreementNumber=0.0, firstSaturday=5.0, numOfColsPerEntry=4.0, numOfServiceDays=22.0, lastDateOfMonth=30.0, trackingColumnsLength=33.0, namesPerRow=8.0, mealcountType=Attendance, monthAsAWord=September}
Aug 19, 2020, 4:12:44 PM
Info
[[Barr, Serena, , , Fri Jun 19 00:00:00 GMT-07:00 2020, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Bonilla, Klay, , , Wed Jan 18 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2017, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Brookes, River, , , Tue Feb 07 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2017, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Burnett, Kaden, , , Sun Sep 11 00:00:00 GMT-07:00 2016, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Coulson, Camille, , , Mon Mar 23 00:00:00 GMT-07:00 2020, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Cruz, Abdulahi, , , Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2018, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Duarte, Ben, , , Wed Jan 04 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2017, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Franco, Shaunie, , , Tue Feb 07 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2017, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Fuller, Roscoe, , , Wed Jan 10 00:00:00 GMT-08:00 2018, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Giles, Gwen, , , Fri Jun 23 00:00:00 GMT-07:00 2017, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants], [Goodman, Jeremiah, , , Thu Aug 31 00:00:00 GMT-07:00 2017, First Day of School, Shelly's Infants],
```

and it goes on.

Notice the first entry in the logs is not what the code calls to print first.

Comment: Your logs? Do note that  it's always you that made the mistake and not the code/js engine.

Comment: Use `console` class instead of `Logger` and view > executions. Provide full logs from start of execution.

Comment: Most probably you're rewriting `i` somewhere else.

Comment: Show full code - always show everything up to the nearest outer lexical scope, especially in cases such as this (unless you know exactly where the problem is or there is too much code, in that case, a minimal reproducible example should suffice).

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

### Apps Script calls to `SpreadsheetApp` run asynchroneously, this brings the sequence of your calls out of order.

1. You should replace your multiple `setValue()` requests through a single `setValues()` request, see [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).
2. You should place after each request to `SpreadsheetApp` a [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) call to make sure that the loop iteration only continues after all calls to `SpreadsheetApp` finished successfully.